# FYI - Beta Graduation

Tags: discussion, public-beta

I just posted [Will the recent flush of Beta graduations impact sites that meet criteria?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331758/217279) on meta.stackexchange and specifilly pointed out that Space Exploration has been meeting the graduation criteria for a while (which it [might not be](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/331759/303080)).

Comment: You should note that the recent announcement is part of the effort to do away with the concept of graduation: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303727/228367

Comment: And that the criteria for sites losing the "beta" label is still being defined.

Comment: The [first question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1/how-far-could-we-send-someone-before-they-get-a-lethal-dose-of-radiation) of the site appeared at 2013-07-16. This was yet in private beta, public beta appeared probably a little later. The current criteria is 7 years of beta running. It is not detailed if it is public or private beta. This criteria will be fullfilled at $\approx$ a year later, at 2020-07-16, or a little bit even later. It is not clear, when and which real features of the graduation (unique design, community migration pathes, etc) will ever appear.

Comment: Btw, considering that also the WindowsPhone SE was graduated, but the Space SE was not, I think it was probably not a well thought decision, although I agree its intent and direction. Note, in this remaining year, also this newly born seven-year rule might change a little bit. What if the CMs decide that it was not a so good idea?

Comment: @peterh from the posts I have seen on meta.se the 7 year rule, was a one time thing.  I have not seen anything suggesting it it be applied as newer sites become 7 years old.

Comment: @JamesJenkins Uhm. Wonderful. So, some sites were renamed to "graduated", not the biggest, not the bests. Beside the "graduation", they did to the sites nothing. But, even this is a huge step: "very little" is still infinite times more than "absolute nothing".

Comment: @peterh Again, they are doing away with the concept of graduation. And James is right that 7 years is not a permanent criteria. They are still working on the criteria.

Comment: @called2voyage Thanks. Well, then don't expect anything. In the foreseeable future, *nothing will change on the SE*. Nothing.

Comment: @peterh I highly doubt that.

Comment: @called2voyage Which was the last time of that anything has really happened, in your remembers?

Comment: @peterh I mean, just last year Quantum Computing left beta and now has a site design. It's not like things haven't been happening. You have to remember how colossal the network is.

Comment: @called2voyage Not true - QC is still a beta site (in the sense of privilege levels, comunity migration pathes). It only has a design and a removed "beta" label, because someone pays for it.

Comment: @peterh the definition of graduation and all the changes we used to anticipate with it are in transition.  It is probably not worth dwelling on what things used to change as opposed to today, and tomorrow...

Comment: @JamesJenkins I am disillusioned in this sense. Nothing happens since I am here. Nothing. Now they *renamed* things to others, and say, that *"from now it will be different!"* I simply don't believe that, that is all. I would be happy if they finally would *change* anything, this is what I most want from them - but I don't believe that it will happen. In any case, future will decide.

Comment: @peterh You're focusing on what hasn't changed, but lots of things have. Not just cosmetically. There have even been elections on sites that don't have site design.

Comment: Concor with @called2voyage Moderator election start on Pets.se in 3 hours https://pets.stackexchange.com/election/1

Comment: @called2voyage Yes, I am focusing what has not changed, and won't be ever: the Stack Exchange site network.

Comment: @called2voyage Btw, I don't think that the CMs would be incompetent in any sense. I think, they have a Boss, who says, "never change a working system". I don't know, who is this Boss, not sure that Spolsky.

Comment: @peterh I've heard your complaints about the system before, but I don't understand how complaining about the absence of change on a post related to actual change is helpful. And if you really believe nothing is going to change, I don't see what help complaining does at all.

Comment: @called2voyage Ok. Time will show it. Be back in a year.

Comment: I noticed that SE.SE has been averaging 8 questions per day. and about 14% of that is uhoh.